# Confusing PHP BCrypt implementation

Tags: php, algorithm, security, mcrypt

I'm trying to find a hashing algorithm to use to save my passwords in the DB (along with a salt). I found this on SO: [How do you use bcrypt for hashing passwords in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4795385/how-do-you-use-bcrypt-for-hashing-passwords-in-php). The top answer has a library that seems to work. I'm just a bit confused by the `verify` method.

To run the script, the author of the library provides:

```
$bcrypt = new Bcrypt(15);

$hash = $bcrypt->hash('password');
$isGood = $bcrypt->verify('password', $hash);
```

The `hash` method takes the input string and hashes it using mcrypt + a salt. The result is returned to $hash. Then the `verify` method takes the same input as `hash` method + $hash. `verify` then calls mcrypt + the value of $hash (instead of some random salt) -- and somehow the results are the same $hash???

Simplified:

```
hash = password + salt
verify = password + hash
verify = hash <-- huh???
```

What did I miss?

**ALSO:**

I plan to modify the code such that `hash` method accepts a $salt parameter. I will make `getSalt` a public method. This way, I can get a salt, store it in the DB, store the hash in the DB, and use user's input + salt to see if it hashes to what I have stored in the DB. **Any problems with this idea?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not familiar with the actual `bcrypt`, but something along the following lines must be what happens:

When you *create* the "hash", `$bcrypt->hash('password')` returns a string that contains both the hash value *and* the initial salt.

When you subsequently say `$bcrypt->verify('password', $mystring)`, the function first reads the salt part out of your input string, then creates the hash again with that salt, and finally compares that computed hash with the hash part of your input string.

In any salinated hashing scheme, you will always have to *store* the salt along with the hash value.

Answer (score 2):

The hash in this case also contains the salt. It's concatenated to the beginning of the string, usually as something like `$2a$12$SALT...`. Passing the hash to `verify` is just done to use that salt value again, the rest of the hash is ignored. That also means you do not need to modify the function for use with salts, that's already part of the algorithm.